# Does the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sin \left(\dfrac{2\pi k!}{2000} \right)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am having som difficulties with series that the title suggests; I would really appreciate some guidance/hint how to get forward. My main difficulty to comprehend is the faculty that appears in the sine and furthermore that the terms in certain intervals of $k$ switches sign... The series apparently converges.

Comment: Take $k \geq 2000$, and each term contributes to 0. Thus, the series converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k$ large enough, $k!$ always has a factor $2000$.  All the terms from then on are zero, so the series converges.

Comment: It only takes $k \ge 15$ to get the factor $2000$, so there are only $14$ nonzero terms.

Answer (score 0):

When $k\geq 2000$, the argument inside the $\sin$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$, so the series actually consists of less than 2000 non-zero terms. Hence it converges.

Answer (score 0):

what can you say about $\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi k!}{2000}\right) \ \text{if} \ k >200$